# Test Case breaking when running the application as a TestNG test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote a java application to use the selenium webdriver to automate few web application tasks. They all worked fine when run as a Java application.

To use the TestNG reporting feature, I ran the application as a TestNG test instead of JAVA application. The same test which was working as JAVA application is failing when I run as testNG.

However, I'm guessing I've setup the TestNG properly since the first testcase which is used to login to the webapp is passing (webLogin method in the code below)

I'm using chromeDriver. I tried removing the main method to run it as testNG application. But it did not work. I made sure that the element path locators I'm using are still valid while using testNG.

```
package myPackage;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import com.google.common.base.Function;

public class checkNavigation {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static WebDriverWait wait;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{

    Configure();        

    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

    webLogin(); 
    addClient();
    addGoal();
    addInsurance();
    validateInputs();
    endSession();
}

@BeforeTest
public static void Configure() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/divyakapa/Desktop/automation/chromedriver");

    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get("https://example.com");  
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public static void webLogin() {
    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"id\"]")).sendKeys("admin");
    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"pw\"]")).sendKeys("password");       
    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ember383\"]/div/div/form/button/span")).click();
}

@Test
public static void addClient() {        
    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ember744\"]/button/div")).click();
    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ember744\"]/div/button[1]/div[2]/div")).click();

    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"newInputFirst\"]")).sendKeys("firstName");
    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"newInputLast\"]")).sendKeys("lastName");
    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"newPersonInputBirthday\"]")).sendKeys("1991");

    Select location = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"newUserInputProvince\"]")));
    location.selectByVisibleText("Place1");

    Select isRetired = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"alreadyRetiredDropdown\"]")));
    isRetired.selectByVisibleText("No");

    Select age = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"newRetirementAge\"]")));
    age.selectByVisibleText("60");

    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"data-entry-modal\"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/button[2]")).click();
}

@Test
public static void addGoal() {
    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ember2328\"]/button/div")).click();

    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ember2328\"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/button[3]")).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ember2464\"]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span"))).click();

    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"basicExpenseInputAmount\"]")).clear();
    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"basicExpenseInputAmount\"]")).sendKeys("90000");
    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ember2563\"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/button[2]")).click();

    // Add income
    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@class=\"add-button \"]")).click();
    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-test-model-type=\"income\"]")).click();

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@class=\"list-group\"]/li[1]"))).click();

    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"employmentInputName\"]")).clear();
    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"employmentInputName\"]")).sendKeys("Company");

    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"employmentInputSalary\"]")).sendKeys("95000");
    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"employmentInputBonus\"]")).sendKeys("5000");
    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"employmentInputBenefitsInKind\"]")).sendKeys("1000");

    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@aria-label=\"Save\"]")).click();

}

@Test
public static void addInsurance() {
    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@class=\"add-button \"]")).click();        
    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-test-model-type=\"protection\"]")).click();

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@class=\"list-group\"]/li[1]"))).click();

    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"termLifeName\"]")).clear();
    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"termLifeName\"]")).sendKeys("BlueCrossBlueShield");
    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ukTermProtectionSalaryMultiplier\"]")).clear();
    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ukTermProtectionSalaryMultiplier\"]")).sendKeys("5");

    Select empId = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"termLifeInsuranceEmploymentId\"]")));
    empId.selectByVisibleText("Company");

    getElement(By.xpath("//*[@aria-label=\"Save\"]")).click();
}

@Test
public static void validateInputs() {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if(!(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@data-test-accordion-header=\"goals\"]")).size() > 0)) throw new NullPointerException("Income Failed to ADD");
    if(!(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@data-test-accordion-header=\"income\"]")).size() > 0)) throw new NullPointerException("Income Failed to ADD");
    if(!(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@data-test-accordion-header=\"protection\"]")).size() > 0)) throw new NullPointerException("Income Failed to ADD");
}

public static WebElement getElement(final By locator) {
    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    WebElement element = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {

        @Override
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver arg0) {
            return arg0.findElement(locator);
        }

    });

        return element;
    }

     @AfterTest
    public static void endSession() {
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Running the above code, the get the following error :

```
Default suite
Total tests run: 5, Failures: 4, Skips: 0
```

I also see that it takes a lot of time (about 10 seconds) before the page is logged in even though that test passes. This does not happen when I run the code as a Java application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show which tests are actually failing? if you are looking for order in testng test execution, it doesn't come by default , so if you have to run test2 after test1 and test3 after test2 etc then you have to use priority(lower the number higher the priority) for ex,

```
@Test(priority=1)
public void Test1() {

}

@Test(priority=2)
public void Test2() {

}

@Test(priority=3)
public void Test3() {

}
```

hope this helps

No, testng never guarantees ordering by default

TestNG relies on reflection. The Java Reflection APIs does not guarantee the method order when we use it to introspect a class to find out what are the test methods that are available in it. So the order of independent methods (Methods that dont have either soft or hard dependency) execution is never guaranteed.

Soft dependency - This is usually achieved in TestNG by using the priority attribute for the @Test annotation. Its called a soft dependency because TestNG will continue to execute all the methods even though a previous method with a higher priority failed.

Hard dependency - This is usually achieved in TestNG by using either dependsOnMethods (or) dependsOnGroups attribute for the @Test annotation. It's called a hard dependency because TestNG will continue to execute a downstream method if and only if an upstream method ran successfully.

Answer (score 1):

By default testng executes methods in alphabetical order of the method names. Typically you would not be using main method for testng. Annotations along with priority are used to set the sequence of executions

Answer (score 1):

Testng framework will run the test methods in alphabetical order. I could see your test methods are dependent and it should in the order. You can set the priorities for your test methods the way you want it to run.

You can refer the below link to set the priority.

[TestNG priority set](https://www.guru99.com/test-case-priority-testng.html)